# How to deploy SOAP Web Service on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, web-services, soap, tomcat7

How do I deploy a SOAP Web Service on Tomcat 7?

I have successfully published my Web Service using Eclipse:

```
"Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:786/AddWebservice", new Operation())"
```

From here I have no idea how to publish the same Web Service on a Tomcat Server.

Answer (score 2):

Deploy JAX-WS web services on Tomcat servlet container. See following summary steps of a web service deployment.

1. Create a web service (of course).
2. Create a sun-jaxws.xml, defines web service implementation class.
3. Create a standard web.xml, defines WSServletContextListener,
   WSServlet and structure of a web project.
4. Build tool to generate WAR file.
5. Copy JAX-WS dependencies to “${Tomcat}/lib” folder.
6. Copy WAR to “${Tomcat}/webapp” folder.
7. Start It.

See the below example [SOAP in Tomcat](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/)

Answer (score 0):

If building as a Maven project, a simple and consistent way to gather runtime dependencies is to add the following dependency (adjust version):

```
<!-- runtime for JAX-WS (servlet implementation) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one way can be used to publish the endpoint is to create a servlet and within doGet() method, publish your endpoint as 
"Endpoint.publish("your_URL", new Operation())" then use "your_URL", to hit the service.